# Generating interrupt on register change (on x86)

Tags: x86, interrupt, cpu-registers

Is it possible - without hardware modification - to force an x86 processor to generate an interrupt when a certain register changes? Specifically, I wish to generate interrupts whenever any of the IA32_RTIT_* registers are changed (only these registers specifically).

If this is possible:

1. how might this be achieved?
2. other than altering IDTR or the IDT, or the firmware, do you think it is feasible for a malware author to disable the generation of the interrupt (if so, how would they achieve this)?

Comment: WRMSR is a privileged instruction, only ring 0 code can execute it.  You can't avoid that interrupt you are looking for.  Have you actually tried this??

Comment: Hi Hans. These specific MSRs control Intel Processor Trace, which I want to use for kernel integrity monitoring (long story... tldr). So I want to detect changes to these MSRs specifically, as modification of these would disable the security mechanism. So, though WRMSR can only be called from ring 0, for my intended purpose the kernel entry interrupt would not by itself be a useful determinant of an attack. I want to be able to be able to interrupt (or otherwise capture in real time) only the register write event. I have not tried this as I don't have experience actually writing assembly. :)

Comment: Just an FYI, you will have a better chance of getting an answer by only asking a single question per post.